# debugging visual C++ properties(hovering over variables does not show value)

Tags: visual-c++

I am working on code written in Visual C++17. But a MS specific feature is used namely properties.
Please note that I am not talking about .NET, but the behavior is similar. Most of my collegues including myself have a lot of experience in C# and hence at first glance these properties seem a handy feature.
This is not managed C++, to emphasize and avoid confusion!

The definition in Visual C++ is as follows :

```
virtual long GetDatumLening() = 0;
virtual void SetDatumLening(long l) = 0;
__declspec(property(get = GetDatumLening, put = SetDatumLening)) long DatumLening;
```

And using it in the code is like this :

```
if (hoofdLening->NietHypothecaireLening && hoofdLening->DatumLening < lControleDatum)
```

Both NietHypothecaireLening and DatumLening are properties defined in the explained manner.

Now my problem is that when I am debugging the application if I hover over those properties the values are not shown whereas properties in C# are shown even if there is some code behind it which is quite nice.

Is there a setting of some kind that I am missing in my Visual Studio environment or is this something I will have to live with ?
The fact that both the getter and setter are virtual should not make a difference, there is of course a non abstract class that implements these methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you see these properties in a ‘Watch’ window?

Comment: no, the watch window complains that there is no member NietHypothecaireLening for instance. Copy pasted the code to make sure I made no typos.